# Getting issues while export Attribute Description in Magento 2

Tags: attributes, magento2.2.2, export, join-table

Export Script to export attribute and its options. It exports attribute and its options perfectly.

But I am trying to get the attribute description by joining this

> ```
>  $select_attribs = $connection->select()
>                 ->from(array('ea'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute')))
>                 ->join(array('c_ea'=>$resource->getTableName('catalog/eav_attribute')), 'ea.attribute_id = c_ea.attribute_id')
> //joined eav/attribute_label table but while executing the script it shows error
>                 ->join(array('ea_l' => $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_label')), 'ea.attribute_id =
> ```
>
> ea_l.attribute_id');

After adding the eav/attribute_label table it shows error like below

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1052 Column 'store_id' in on clause is ambiguous

```
 **My Export Script**


    <?php
        define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
        require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
        Mage::app();
         $entity_type_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();

        prepareCollection($entity_type_id);

        function prepareCollection($ent_type_id){
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $select_attribs = $connection->select()
                    ->from(array('ea'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute')))
                    ->join(array('c_ea'=>$resource->getTableName('catalog/eav_attribute')), 'ea.attribute_id = c_ea.attribute_id')
    //joined eav/attribute_label table but while executing the script it shows error
                    ->join(array('ea_l' => $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_label')), 'ea.attribute_id = ea_l.attribute_id');


            $product_attributes = $connection->fetchAll($select_prod_attribs);

            $select_attrib_option = $select_attribs
                                        ->join(array('e_ao'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option'), array('option_id')), 'c_ea.attribute_id = e_ao.attribute_id')
                                        ->join(array('e_aov'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option_value'), array('value')), 'e_ao.option_id = e_aov.option_id and store_id = 0')
                                        ->order('e_ao.attribute_id ASC');

            $product_attribute_options = $connection->fetchAll($select_attrib_option);

            $attributesCollection = mergeCollections($product_attributes, $product_attribute_options);
            prepareCsv($attributesCollection);

        }

        function mergeCollections($product_attributes, $product_attribute_options){

            foreach($product_attributes as $key => $_prodAttrib){
                $values = array();
                $attribId = $_prodAttrib['attribute_id'];
                foreach($product_attribute_options as $pao){
                    if($pao['attribute_id'] == $attribId){
                        $values[] = $pao['value'];
                    }
                }
                if(count($values) > 0){
                    $values = implode(";", $values);
                    $product_attributes[$key]['_options'] = $values;
                }
                else{
                    $product_attributes[$key]['_options'] = "";
                }
                /*
                    temp
                */
                $product_attributes[$key]['attribute_code'] = $product_attributes[$key]['attribute_code'];
            }

            return $product_attributes;

        }

        function prepareCsv($attributesCollection, $filename = "importAttrib.csv", $delimiter = '|', $enclosure = '"'){

            $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
            $first = true;
            foreach ($attributesCollection as $line) {
                if($first){
                    $titles = array();
                    foreach($line as $field => $val){
                        $titles[] = $field;
                    }
                    fputcsv($f, $titles, $delimiter, $enclosure);
                    $first = false;
                }
                fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter, $enclosure); 
            }
            fseek($f, 0);
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            fpassthru($f);
        }
```

Comment: Check my solution, it will solve your issue thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You need to specify the `tableName` since multiple tables contains the same column name (`store_id`).

Add your table name like `table.store_id`.